# How to use codepipline to deploy to other region

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline

I wanna do something pretty simple, a pipeline which deliver content of an aws codecommit repo to a S3 on another region.
From what I see I have  to create the pipeline on the codecommit region otherwise I can't access it.
From what I have read codepipline support across regions actions. However I have an error in the deploy stage :
Replication of artifact 'SourceOutput' failed: Failed replicating artifact from ao-content-deploy-codepipelineartifactstorebucket-xxx in eu-west-1 to ao-content-deploy-codepipelineartifactstorebucket-xxx in us-east-2: The destination artifact bucket is in a different region. Please use a artifact bucket in the same region.

I'm not sure on how to proceed ? can anybody help ? just confirm that it's possible ?

Thanks for your help.
Best

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the S3 Deploy action, by chance?

What you want is a pipeline configured with an artifact bucket for each region you want cross-region actions. And you need to specify the region for cross-region actions. This is described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-create-cross-region.html